# Standard apps like Firefox, loaded via browser as .dmg, do not start anymore (MacOS Monterey 12.3.1)

Tags: macos, macos-monterey

Having a Mac Mini, some days ago I updated it to Monterey 12.3.1. Since then (at least I guess) I cannot start apps that I downloaded as .dmg via web browsers (not via App Store). E. g. these standard apps do not start:

- Firefox: https://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/mac/
- Open Office: https://www.openoffice.de/openoffice_download_macosx.php
- DBeaver: https://dbeaver.io/download/
- ...

After clicking the downloaded .dmg, a window opens, asking me to move the app to /Applications. I click the app on the left (or moving it to /Applications and click there). Then, a dock icon gets visible and moves up and down two minutes, and remains. No application or error window appears.

The "Allow downloads from App Store and trusted developers" option is checked in the security settings, of course. And while launching, the server log shows "CoreServicesUIAgent Connection from process XXXX **does not have the required entitlement com.apple.private.iscsuia**", followed by an exit.

Any ideas how to solve this problem are appreciated.

Comment: *"dock icon gets visible and moves up and down two minutes"* …what dock icon? Once you've copied the app & put away the disk image, then what are you doing?

Comment: With "dock icon" I mean the app icon in the dock bar (the bar showing all the app icons) at the bottom that shows up after clicking the .app file. Before the macOS update, I could click the app icon on the left (in the window that opened after clicking the .dmg file in my web browser), and the app started. Moving the icon on the left to the Applications folder on the right (as suggested by the arrow) copies the app into applications. I then open the Applications folder with Finder and doubleclick. In either way, the app does not start as described.

Comment: Dragging from the .dmg to Apps shouldn't make a new Dock icon. That will only generate once the newly-copied app is running from Applications - at which point you can move it in the Dock to become permanent. Any app downloaded & copied this way should then be opened at first run by right clicking in Applications & selecting Open. Successive launches will work from double-click or from the Dock icon if you make one. [If you have previously made a Dock icon from an older version, then the Dock icon will link to the new version, but you will still have to run by right-click the first time]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But still after doubleclick or Right Menu > open in the Finder, the same happens: The dock icon keeps bouncing for about two minutes and the app doesn't show up. Interestingly, the dock icon never disappears after these two minutes. Instead, it remains visible. And while being visible, I a) cannot delete the .app (Hint: "Cannot be deleted because the app is running"), and b) a Right-click on the dock icon and "Show all windows" says the hint "there are no windows". So, the app seems to be running invisibly in the background but no app window shows up...

Comment: Reboot & try again. Both regular double-click or right click should spring a dialog on first run, holding up the app until cleared - maybe it's on another Space, hidden behind something, or failing to show at all. The dialog doesn't belong to the app, it belongs to System, so it won't register as a window to the app.

Comment: Thank you, but rebooting didn't help. After another day of debugging I have found a partly solution for my problem which obviously depends on how the .dmg is launched. See discussion here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706210 (especially post #3). Maybe you have a hint how to fix this new problem?

Comment: Problem solved :) See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Other unclosed warning windows prevented the window "This application was downloaded from internet. Do you really want to open it?", preventing to launch the app that was clicked in the .dmg volume folder. Further details see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706210.